Crash When Showing Interstitial Ad in Jetpack Compose Due to Local Current Context Cast as Activity
I'm working on an Android app using Jetpack Compose and I'm trying to show an interstitial ad using InterstitialAd.show(context as Activty) inside a composable screen. However, I'm getting a crash when casting LocalContext.current to Activity in order to call the show() method for the ad. This crash started occurring after I updated the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 35.
Eception:
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.zz.zzworld/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?
Here’s the code I’m using to cast the context and display the ad:

InterstitialAds.getInstance().mInterstitialAd?.show(context as Activity)



So I resolved this crash just by adding following in the manifest file incase of API level 35

